# How to show that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{1}{i\cdot2^i}=\ln2$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have no idea about showing that:

$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{1}{i\cdot2^i}=\ln2$$

And what about more general situation(replace 2 with a constant $\alpha$)?

Could anyone please give me a helping hand? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You know that the dummy variable is $i$, but in the sum you typed $x$, right? Also maybe you should start at $i=1$.

Comment: As a hint, think about the power series of $\ln(1-x)$.

Comment: Also, please search on approach0.xyz before asking, since often your question has been asked and answered before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with the geometric series. For $|x|<1$ it holds
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k =\frac{1}{1-x}$$
Integration renders:
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k}x^{k} =-ln (1-x)$$
Setting $x=1/2$ renders your formula.

Answer (score 3):

At first, start by using the power series of $ln(1-x)$. Then,

[image]
For a more general constant (say $a $), use $1/a $ instead of $1/2$. But this is true as long as $|a| \geq 1$

Answer (score 1):

The basic question has been answered.  A generalization is $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k\alpha^k}=\ln(\frac \alpha {\alpha-1})$$